# Using a decorator to register functions across different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, python-decorators

I have a list of functions that will be organized under different modules based on their properties and logic. I want to use a decorator to add them all to a single registry (i.e. a dictionary) so that I can dynamically select the desired function based on their name.

So I'll have the following structure:

```
# project_dir/registry.py

REGISTRY = {}

def register_func(func_name):
    def func_decoractor(func):
        REGISTRY[func_name] = func
    return func_decorator
```

And in another module:

```
# project_dir/funcA.py

@register_func("foo")
def funcA():
   ...
```

I keep running into circular imports when I try to use this hierarchy. How would I approach this implementation?

Comment: Can you explain how are you getting into circular imports? I tried the approach posted and didn't run into this problem.

Comment: The module and the function have the same name?